# View is not updating between components in anuglar 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I'm working on simple CRUD app using angular2. I have `ProductListComponent` which displays list of products, further this component has two child components `ProductDetailComponent` and `ProductUpdateComponent`.

`ProductUpdateComponent` will open modal and submits forms, after successful submission I navigate to `ProductListComponent`. So after successful update when I'm navigating to `ProductListComponent`,  the view is not updating with new data (product list is not updating)

**ProductListComponent**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'product-list',
   moduleId: module.id,
   templateUrl: 'product-list.component.html',
   directives: [ProductDetailComponent, ProductUpdateComponent],
   providers: [ProductService]
})

export class ProductListComponent {
   public products: any;
   constructor(private productService: ProductService) {
        this.productService.getAllProducts()
            .subscribe(
                response => this.products = response.products
            );
   }
```

}

**ProductUpdateComponent**

```
Component({
   selector: 'product-form',
   moduleId: module.id,
   templateUrl: 'product-form.component.html',
   providers: [CheckFormErrors, ProductService]
})

export class ProductFormComponent {
     productForm: ControlGroup;
     formFields: Array<string>;
     view: string;

     @Input()
     pr: Product;
     // form stuff goes here

     // after form submitted
     saveProduct() {
         if (this.productForm.dirty && this.productForm.valid) {
            let form = this.productForm.value
            let formProduct = new Product({
                code: form.code,
                name: form.name,
                price: form.price,
                packing: form.packing,
                description: form.description
            });

            this.productService.updateProduct(this.pr, formProduct)

            // navigate to ProductList
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
            console.log("competed")
    }
  }
```

Please check the detailed full code here :
https://bitbucket.org/asifpy/inventory-manager/src

Comment: You are creating two instances of ProductService because it is in multiple `providers` arrays.  Try putting ProductService only into one `providers` array that is higher up in the component tree.  Then ProductListComponent and ProductFormComponent will get an instance of the same/single ProductService.

Comment: I removed ProductService from `ProductFormComponent`, now ProductListComponent aready has product service but sti no luck

Comment: You should add productService only in parent of productUpdate and productListConponet.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the ajax request is working and the the data is being saved on the backend?

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal: I added productService in `app.component` which is parent of `productList` and `ProductUpdate`. But still the same issue. After update form submitted, I have to refresh the same page to see the updated data

Comment: I am nor sure what are you trying to accomplish. you are already in the list view, you need to rebind the updated list array to the model.

Comment: @Avi: You mean after successful save I need to send updated products list? But I'm already navigating to `ProductListComponent` which means my service should fetch updated products list from server. Also after form submission, if I refresh the product list page, then I'm already seeing updated list which means there is no problem from server end.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't structured correctly.
look at this code:

```
saveProduct() {
    if (this.productForm.dirty && this.productForm.valid) {
      let form = this.productForm.value
      let formProduct = new Product({
        code: form.code,
        name: form.name,
        price: form.price,
        //stock: form.stock,
        packing: form.packing,
        description: form.description
      });

      if(this.pr){
        this.productService.updateProduct(this.pr, formProduct)
      }
      else{
        this.productService.addProduct(formProduct)
      }
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
      console.log("competed")
    }
  }
```

your code doesn't wait for the http call to end before you navigate.
but you don't need to navigate. you need to refresh the products model upon response. for a quick fix change the add and update functions to return the http observable, subscribe to them and on the call back do your route.